# Store content from Excel file with image in DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, image, datatable, oledb

I searched around the Internet but didn't find something that matches my case.
I'm using OleDb to read Excel files. Now I have one file which contains an Image (together with Text). Is it possible somehow to store not only the text from the Excel file into a DataTable but also the Image in the same constellation like they are in the file?

Thanks in advance!